# Why does REINFORCE perform badly at first in Sutton and Barto Figure 13.1?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, sutton-barto, reinforce

In Sutton and Barto ([PDF](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf), page 265), 2nd edition, Figure 13.1 applies REINFORCE to the "short corridor with switched actions" environment from Example 13.1. The figure looks like this:

[image]

My question is, why is the initial performance so poor? I believe it should be close to optimal even without any training.

My reasoning is this: If we initialize the algorithm with $\boldsymbol{\theta} = \boldsymbol{0}$, then the initial policy has

$$\pi({\tt right}|s,\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \frac{e^{\theta_1}}{e^{\theta_1} + e^{\theta_2}} = 0.5.$$

And from the figure in Example 13.1 (p. 323) --

[image]

-- we know that a policy that goes $\tt{right}$ with probability 0.5 in every state has an expected value that is very close to that of the optimal policy, around $-12$ or so. So shouldn't the policies produced by REINFORCE start close to optimal with essentially no training, and then just improve little to none after that?

My own experiment supports my hunch:

[image]

But it's possible I'm doing something wrong, both theoretically and computationally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm actually working on this example too, implemented the REINFORCE algorithm, and got the same result as you. My only guess is that the authors chose a different initial $\theta$ value to show the convergence properties for different choices of $\alpha$. (For example maybe something like $\theta_0 = [-3; 0]$ so the initial probability of right action is ~0.05 and the initial expected cost is quite large.)

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I tried setting the initial theta to $(-3, 0)$ and got a curve much more like Sutton and Barto's. The curves are nearly identical for the three values of $\alpha$, so that's another question mark, but I'll leave that one for now.

Comment: This is exactly right. In a toy example such as the above it is clear what a good starting point could be, but in eg a deep neural network this is not the case.

Comment: I guess what was confusing is that the pseudocode for the algorithm suggests initializing $\theta$ to 0, which just happens to be a good starting point for this toy problem, but the plot shows something different and there's no comment about why.